# Java syntax error while trying to learn for loops

Tags: java

I am trying to teach myself Java, and am learning about `for loops`.  I am trying to write a short and simple program that gives me the following output:

1

1 4

1 4 9

1 4 9 25

I have a feeling I am getting tripped up in the exponent portion.  My source code is as follows:

```
public class Forloop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(int j = Math.pow(j,i));
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone provide me any help as to where I have gone wrong, and perhaps the fix to it.  Much thanks.

Comment: it is j to the power 2 (not i) and remove assignment in print method

Comment: and 25 in the last column isn't 16 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have a variable declaration in your print statement. Just write like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(Math.pow(j, i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to write the declaration on it's own line. You would have to name it something other than `j` though, since you already have that variable declared:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            int exp = (int) Math.pow(j, i);
            System.out.print(exp);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Also, as @JigarJoshi points out, you don't need the `Math.pow()` method to achieve your output, since you are outputting squares. This will do what you are aiming for:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j * j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure about pow method ?

Comment: MUCH THANKS!  Yes, I think I went a bit to far, but @JigarJoshi's advice was great.  Definitely still learning a lot, but you guys give me some hope.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print((int) Math.pow(j, 2));
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
1
1 4
1 4 9
1 4 9 16
1 4 9 16 25
```

Answer (score 0):

As Keppil said you cannot have a variable declaration within your print statement.
However, you can initialize a variable in your statement.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int j2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j2 = (int) Math.pow(j, i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `int j = Math.pow(j,i)` inside `System.out.print`. What is your logic there?
You can simply print by `System.out.print(Math.pow(j,i))`;